# Can "If he was hungry, he would eat something" be interpreted as an open conditions in the past?

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

> i) If he was hungry, he would eat something.

This is an example sentence of unreal conditionals (he is not hungry) in my textbook.

> ii)I used to live near the library. If I wanted a book, I would go and get one.

This is an example sentence of open conditions in the past in *Oxford guide to English Grammar*. I wonder if the sentence i can be interpreted as an open conditions in the past as in ii.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Your sentence (1) is ambiguous as to whether it means (2) or (3):

1. If he was hungry, he would eat something.
2. If he were hungry, he would eat something.
3. When(ever) he was hungry, he would eat something.

Here (2) is a counterfactual event, while (3) is merely a routine activity that operated continuously in the past.

Comment: Or (2) *...he would **have eaten** something*.